# React native becomes slow in mobile. Javascript code takes 3-4 seconds to execute in emulator however, when installed in apk it beocmes slow

Tags: react-native

React-native application becomes very slow and takes around 2 mins to run when installed in mobile. However, in emulator it takes around 3-4 secs. The code has a lot of javascript code and for loops written in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be due to your emulator hardware is less compared with physical device and you can usually experience that difference of loading time, to overcome that loading we have a concept of `Splash Screen` which will hide that loading from users.